# Convert list to lower-case

Tags: python, lowercase

I'm trying to get this column of words in input.txt:

```
Suzuki music
Chinese music
Conservatory
Blue grass
Rock n roll
Rhythm
Composition
Contra
Instruments
```

into this format:

```
"suzuki music", "chinese music", "conservatory music", "blue grass", "rock n roll", "rhythm"...
```

This code:

```
with open ('artsplus_stuff.txt', 'r') as f:
    list.append(", ".join(['%s' % row for row in f.read().splitlines()]))
    for item in list:
        item.lower()

print list
```

returns a list, but the first letters are capitalized.

['Suzuki music, Chinese music, Conservatory, Blue grass, Rock n roll, Rhythm, Composition, Contra, Instruments ']

How do I get all the items lower-cased?

Thanks!

---

Answer isn't working on this list:

```
Chess
Guitar
Woodworking
Gardening
Car_restoration
Metalworking
Marksman
Camping
Backpacking_(wilderness)
Hunting
Fishing
Whittling
Geocaching
Sports
Model_Building
Leatherworking
Bowling
Archery
Hiking
Connoisseur
Photography
Pool_(cue_sports)
Mountaineering
Cooking
Blacksmith
Aviator
Magic_(illusion)
Foreign_language
Card_game
Blog
Paintball
Fencing
Brewing
Amateur_Astronomy
Genealogy
Adventure_racing
Knitting
Computer_Programming
Amateur_radio
Audiophile
Baking
Bboying
Baton_twirling
Chainmail
Constructed_language
Coloring
Crocheting
Creative_writing
Drawing
Fantasy_Football
Fishkeeping
Home_automation
Home_Movies
Jewelry
Knapping
Lapidary_club
Locksport
Musical_Instruments
Painting
RC_cars
Scrapbooking
Sculpting
Sewing
Singing
Writing
Air_sports
Boardsport
Backpacking
Bonsai
Canoeing
Cycling
Driving
Freerunning
Jogging
Kayaking
Motor_sports
Mountain_biking
Machining
Parkour
Rock_climbing
Running
Sailing
Sand_castle
Sculling
Rowing_(sport)
Human_swimming
Tai_Chi
Vehicle_restoration
Water_sports
Antiques
Coin_collecting
Element_collecting
Stamp_collecting
Vintage_car
Vintage_clothing
Record_Collecting
Antiquities
Car_audio
Fossil_collecting
Insect_collecting
Leaf
Metal_detectorist
Mineral_collecting
Petal
Rock_(geology)
Seaglass
Seashell
Boxing
Combination_puzzle
Contract_Bridge
Cue_sports
Darts
Table_football
Team_Handball
Airsoft
American_football
Association_football
Auto_racing
Badminton
Climbing
Cricket
Disc_golf
Figure_skating
Footbag
Kart_racing
Plank_(exercise)
Racquetball
Rugby_league
Table_tennis
Microscopy
Reading_(process)
Shortwave_listening
Videophile
Aircraft_spotting
Amateur_geology
Birdwatching
Bus_spotting
Gongoozler
Meteorology
Travel
Board_game
Airbrush
Advocacy
Acting
model_aircraft
Pets
Aquarium
Astrology
Astronomy
Backgammon
Base_Jumping
Sun_tanning
Beachcombing
Beadwork
Beatboxing
Campanology
Belly_dance
cycle_Polo
Bicycle_motocross
Boating
Boomerang
Volunteering
Carpentry
Butterfly_Watching
Button_Collecting
Cake_Decorating
Calligraphy
Candle
Cartoonist
Casino
Cave_Diving
Ceramic
Church
Cigar_Smoking
Cloud_Watching
Antique
Hat
album
Gramophone_record
trading_card
Musical_composition
Worldbuilding
Cosplay
Craft
Cross-Stitch
Crossword_Puzzle
Diecast
Digital_Photography
Dodgeball
Doll
Dominoes
Dumpster_Diving
restaurant
education
Electronics
Embroidery
Entertainment
physical_exercise
Falconry
List_of_fastest_production_cars
Felt
Poi_(performance_art)
Floorball
Floristry
Fly_Tying
off-roading
ultimate_(sport)
Game
Garage_sale
Ghost_Hunting
Glowsticking
Gunsmith
Gyotaku
Handwriting
Hang_gliding
Herping
HomeBrewing
Home_Repair
Home_Theater
Hot_air_ballooning
Hula_Hoop
Ice_skating
Impersonator
Internet
Invention
Jewellery
Jigsaw_Puzzle
Juggling
diary
skipping_rope
amateur_Chemistry
Kite
snowkiting
knot
Laser
Lawn_Dart
poker
Leather_crafting
Lego
Macramé
Model_Car
Matchstick_Model
Meditation
Metal_Detector
Rail_transport_modelling
Model_Rocket
ship_model
scale_model
Motorcycle
Needlepoint
Origami
Papermaking
Papier-mâché
Parachuting
Paragliding
Pinochle
Pipe_Smoking
Pottery
Powerbocking
Demonstration_(people)
Puppetry
Pyrotechnics
Quilting
pigeon_racing
Rafting
Railfan
Rapping
remote_control
Relaxation
Renaissance_Fair
Renting_movies
Robotics
Rock_Balancing
Role-playing
sand_art_and_play
Scuba_Diving
Self-Defense
Skeet_Shooting
Skiing
Shopping
choir
Skateboarding
Sketch_(drawing)
SlackLining
Sleep
Slingshot
Slot_Car_Racing
Snorkeling
Soap
Rubik's_Cube
caving
Family
Storm_Chasing
Storytelling
String_Figure
Surf_Fishing
Survival_skills
Tatting
Taxidermy
Tea_Tasting
Tesla_Coil
Tetris
Textile
stone_Rubbing
Antique_tool
Toy
Treasure_Hunting
Trekkie
tutoring
Urban_Exploration
Video_Game
Violin
Volunteer
Walking
Weightlifting
Windsurfing
WineMaking
Wrestling
Zip-line
traveling
```

error:     list.append(", ".join(['"%s"' % row for row in f.read().splitlines()]))
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'
logout

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: ...and becuase they are immutable you're `lower` ing a *copy* of the string in question.

Comment: This is the obligatory "don't name a variable `list` because `list` is a python builtin" comment.

Comment: @goldisfine, whenever you say "isn't working", paste the error or describe the results you're getting.

Comment: As many of these comments have stated, use a variable that isn't named `list`.  To create a new list, you can write something like `l = []`.  I believe that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This was very helpful. I've learned: strings are immutable, not to name my lists "list", and to paste erros.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Instead of

```
for item in list:
    item.lower()
```

change the name of the variable `list` to `l` or whatever you like that *isn't* a reserved word in Python and use the following line, obviously substituting whatever you name the list for `l`.

```
l = [item.lower() for item in l]
```

The `lower` method returns a copy of the string in all lowercase letters.  Once a string has been created, nothing can modify its contents, so you need to create a new string with what you want in it.

Answer (score 13):

Here is how it can be done:

```
In [6]: l = ['Suzuki music', 'Chinese music', 'Conservatory', 'Blue grass']

In [7]: map(str.lower, l)
Out[7]: ['suzuki music', 'chinese music', 'conservatory', 'blue grass']
```

One of the reasons your code doesn't behave as expected is that `item.lower()` doesn't modify the string (in Python, strings are immutable). Instead, it *returns* the lowercase version of the string, which your code then disregards.

Comment: Yay for functional programming.

Comment: Considering that the asker's problem was that he was performing an operation he intuitively expected to modify the list in place but in fact was not, giving as an answer *another operation that doesn't modify the list in place* and not explaining to him his mistake seems like a fairly unhelpful reply.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest might be a list comprehension:

```
with open('./input.txt', 'r') as f:
    results = [ line.strip().lower() for line in f if line]
```

... I'm assuming you're willing to strip all leading and trailing whitespace from each line; though you could use just `.rstrip()` or even `.rstrip('\n')` to be more specific in that.  (One would preserve any whitespace on the left of each line, and the other would strip *only* the newlines from the ends of the lines.

Also this will filter out any blank lines, including the terminal empty line which is almost always found at the end of a text file.  (This code will work even with the rare text file that doesn't end with a newline).

Comment: Full answer. You rock Dennis!

Answer (score 1):

You can use method str.lower().

Answer (score 1):

For those who like timing tests

```
In [1]: %timeit [c.lower() for c in l]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 866 ns per loop

In [2]: %timeit map(str.lower, l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit map(lambda x:x.lower(), l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simply we can convert list into small latter do this.**

```
>>> words = ["PYTHON", "PROGRAMMING"]
>>> type((words))
>>> for i in words:
          print(i.lower())
```

output:

```
python programming
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python strings are immutable. However they can be replaced and they can be replaced by the same variable name. Instead of creating another variable use the same.

```
myList = ["Suzuki music", "Chinese music", "Conservatory music", "Blue grass", "Rock n roll", "Rhythm"]

for i in range(0, len(myList)):
   myList[i] = myList[i].lower()

for item in myList:
   print item
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another method:

```
my_list = ['John', 'michael', 'Robert', 'James']
new_list = []

for name in my_list:
    new_list.append(name.lower())

print(new_list)
```